# Connection Loop With "Ethernet to USB" adapters problem

Tags: android, connection, streaming, ethernet

I have a problem with my video streaming connection setup.

I'm trying to create a cabled connection setup. But I have a problem.
My setup is between two android devices and here is the connections;

Device A -> usb-ethernet adapter -> ethernet cable -> ethernet-usb adapter -> Device B

I can create a connection and send pings between both devices but there is no smooth values on it.
E.g My exceptation is about 1ms but there is 10-13 ms and sometimes it can be 1500ms and etc. And because of it I lost my video streaming and see unsafe connection.

I think there is a loop between two ethernet to usb adapter and source of my problem is that loop.

That is the question, how can I prevent that loop and create stable connection with this setup? Is there any idea about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Device A -> usb-ethernet adapter -> ethernet cable -> ethernet-usb adapter -> Device B

There's no loop. A loop requires a bridge/switch and an additional (redundant) link.

Any round-trip delay beyond 1 ms indicates a larger problem: bad cable, duplex mismatch, crappy USB adapters, crappy TCP/IP stack, network congestion, CPU overload.

A simple IPv4 over Ethernet ping (default 32 bytes data) has a total size of 8(L1) + 18(L2) + 20(L3) + 8(ICMP) + 32(data) = 86 bytes. Even over 10 Mbit/s that's just .14 ms plus processing overhead (perhaps another .1 ms).